# Dagger 2 Component not generated in android studio

Tags: android, dagger-2

dagger2 component not generated in my MainActivity class.
i write is line in my Gradle project file:

`classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'`

and also this lines in my Gradle module:

```
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.17'
compileOnly 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.17"
```

and sync my project, but still not working.

Comment: try rebuldilding project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for Dagger components to be generated, you need to do a `Build` of your project. Doing a `Clean` will remove all dagger generated components and `Build` will recreate these components